# Fedex realtime not sending line 1 of address

Tags: magento-enterprise, fedex

We have a EE 1.1.3.1 store setup with FedEx realtime shipping. This works fine for street address request but not for P.O. Boxes.

When entering a PO Box, Fed Ex returns rates, where as it should not.

Upon contacting Fed Ex, they indicated that address line1 was not sent in the data packet. The information received was Postal Code, Country, and Residency. They indicated that to fix the problem, line1 information would need to be included in the sent transaction.

Magento support acknowledged the issue but will not fix this or provides a patch.

Does anyone know where to modify the data send to FedEx? It looks like data is passed into fedex.php api script through the function getConfigData().

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

shipping quotes at fedex depends on:

- package type (eg: pak)
- recipient zone (eg: zone 4 -> japan)
- weight (0.5 up to 68kgs for international priority).
- ODA: if its an out of delivery area package eg: okinawa in japan.

if you put a valid postal code and country it will give you the associated cost for that package.

address1 and address2 are not analized by fedex shipping engine. probably it will take into consideration if all characters ar ASCII but they will not check for that address worldwide.

the first check for that usually is the courier that picks up the package. hope it helps.